# 2.15GA Current?

Tags: current

I'm using this app called iCircuit for Android (I'm asking here because the iCurcuit forum has been forsaken) and when I have a circuit with a 3V battery and an LED, it lists the current as 2.15GA. I'm new to electronics so I'm wondering why its giving me this because I have connected an LED to a 3V battery before and its been fine.
[image]

Comment: .. if you don't have a current limiting resistor, then you get _all the current in the universe_ :)

Comment: Wow that must be a *bright* LED!

Comment: @JYelton: For a tiny fraction of a second. Then it becomes the world's brightest arc lamp.

Comment: I wonder what is the current if you set the voltage to 30V.

Comment: @Codism just for fun I tried it, it stops the simulation after 6.1V, at which point the current is 464.16YA. lol.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simulator is pretending that the battery is an ideal power source, i.e. no internal resistance. As such, it is using the largest possible value it can support, 2147483647A.

True power sources *do* have an internal resistance, and this is what is preventing the LED you put across it from burning out. LEDs *should* have a resistor placed in series with them so that you don't have to depend on this internal resistance.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks. (I would upvote and not comment but not enough rep...)

Comment: The simulator is also evidently failing to model LED bulk resistance. Even if the power source is idealized, there is no excuse for this.

Comment: more on LED resistance: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76367/accounting-for-led-resistance/76378#76378